# “limitative factor” vs “limiting factor”

Tags: word-choice, grammar, adjectives

From the Exam book, *Cambridge English FIRST 1 (2014)*, Test 2, paper 1: *Reading and Use of English*. The aim is to modify the word in caps so that it fits in the gap on the same line.

> **Running Speed**
>
> […] For years, it was assumed that simple muscle power determined human speed, but recent research suggests otherwise. The most important **(19)** ....... factor
>    appears to be how **LIMIT** quickly the muscles can contract and thus **(20)**..... the time a runner's foot is in **MINIMUM** contact with the ground.

My private student wrote  **limitative** for No.19, but the answers at the back of the book say the correct answer is **limiting**. Although I agree that “[limiting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limiting)” sounds better,  I believe that my student's answer “[limitative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limitative)” is also grammatically correct. The book offers no explanation and no other possible alternative.

> - *limiting*: functioning as a limit
> - *limitative*:  limiting, restrictive

**Question**

- Is *limitative* grammatically incorrect for answer **(19)**? I can't figure out why Cambridge doesn't also accept *limitative*, could someone explain?

Thanks.

Comment: I think *limitative* is correct here. But the word is extremely rare, so the test setters probably didn't even think of it: [See Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=limitative+factor%2C+limiting+factor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Climitative%20factor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Climiting%20factor%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I have never heard/read "limitative" before.  But according to the dictionary it means "limiting" and is presumably a valid answer.  (Do advise the student that it's a rare word and should not generally be used, though.)

Comment: I can imagine why you student wrote limitative instead of limiting. As a far as I know, the accepted  choice in those exams is the best, most used use, but it does not necessarily imply that other possible choices are wrong.

Comment: @Josh61 and *limitative* is in the OED, a rare word is "rare" not "wrong". I only wanted to be sure there wasn't a grammatical reason.

Comment: I didn't say it is wrong, but I think that, having to chose between the two, limiting is the "winner".

Comment: Fine, I also said It sounded "better" but if it isn't obsolete, nor archaic, nor ungrammatical, then a candidate shouldn't be penalized. So, is that it? Any word can be grammatical if enough speakers use it in a certain way... suppose so.

Comment: As many of those that answered, I think that both limiting and limitative are correct answers: the 2 words are quite synonyms. However, in my opinion, the slight difference may be that "limitative" refers to a restrictive condition (e.g. a contract clause) and "limiting" is less generic, as it is related to some limit value (e.g. a threshold).

Answer (score 2):

**Limitative** relating to limits, having to do with limits.

**Limiting**  imposing a limit.

The -ive suffix in the adjective **limitative** would indicate that a noun modified by that adjective would relate or pertain to limits, that it has some of the characteristics of a limit, or while itself not being a limit per se could function much like one or as one. That constellation of meanings is only nibbling at the edges of what is needed in the sentence.

In other words, researchers considered a number of **limitative** factors, i.e. factors of a kind that could serve to impose a limit. But the most important of the **limiting** factors, i.e. factors actually imposing a limit, was speed of muscle contraction.

Comment: Limiting is the answer.

Comment: Also limitative means "imposing a limit" http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/limitative. For some reason it is uncommon.

Comment: Collins offers a very loosy goosy definition.

Comment: whereas your definition (from where?)  is filled to the brim with detail. :) Would you mind stating in your answer that *limiting* is the answer, and, perhaps,  explain "why"?

Comment: Can you give a source for your definition?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider similar word pairs, such as

punitive-punishing
diminutive-diminishing
corroborative-corroborating
relative-relating

... you'll see that in each pair the first word's function is to modify something that has possibilities, whilst the second one is used when describing something concrete: a certainty.

Just a theory.

Comment: @Rathony: Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year and all.

Comment: @Rathony: I'll try not to.

Comment: So, are you saying that both "limitative" and "limiting factors" are grammatical, only its meaning changes?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I'm saying no such thing. "Limitative" is a nonsensical word. As is "grammatical," come to think of it. I didn't put any of that in the answer lest someone should take umbrage and all.

Comment: That's interesting, you should edit your answer and include that reflection. Nowhere does your post say that *limitative factor* is nonsensical, how was I to infer that? And no, you didn't mention anything about its grammar, but I did in my question, and that is why I asked.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Like I said earlier, somebody might take offense. Some questions aren't suitable for this forum. How were you to infer that? Are you serious? You're a native speaker, aren't you. Certain nuances should be ... shouldn't be ... uh ... lost on you, then.

Comment: Where did you say someone might take offence? Are you saying my question is off-topic? Limitative factor doesn't sound great, but as a word, [*limitative*](http://findwords.info/term/limitative), is cited by the OED, and is at least 500 years old.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Your question is on topic. So would have been my answer if it weren't for people who ... never mind. A word's _age_ is no concern of mine. Suffice it to say that it was just as nonsensical 500 years ago. The OED contains quite a few of those. It says that evolution is a theory, whereas anyone who's even superficially familiar with the scientific method knows that it's barely a hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what I'm thinking.

Many exams degenerate into that form without realizing it.  It's not fair but it's true.  I've had to grade papers after running into this issue myself.  Best way to deal with it is to explain your thinking.

My answer to 19 by the way would probably be: deciding. Why can I do that? Because the instructions didn't limit the definition of what it means to modify a word. So I modified into a whole new word.  Yes, I was a difficult student in school.

Limiting is far more popular than limitative.  There is no grammatical justification to pick one over the other.  It's entirely unreasonable to expect the book to be perfect.  I'd say the student deserves the point.  I also think the student needs a mark on their paper because this is a teaching moment.

Being correct is no excuse to be ignorant.  You owe it to this student to make clear this is not the popular choice, even if it is a correct one.